# Best way to name async method

Tags: api-design

Where is an API of, let’s say, one method: “DoSomething()”. There should be two versions of the method: asynchronous and synchronous. We should encourage API users to use async one so sync one probably should get more complicated and explicit name.
So the problem is: how should we name this pair. To the date we’ve came up with:

- DoSomethingAndWaitForResult() / DoSomething()
- DoSomething() / DoSomethingAsync()
- DoSomethingSync() / DoSomething()
- DoSomething() / RequestSomething()

None of above schemes seems like optimal for us. Any suggestion folks?

*Update.* BTW do not hesitate to post one of the above as an answer if it fit you.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to encourage your user to use async ones over sync, then I'd go for this one : `DoSomethingSync() / DoSomething()`

However, tell your users **loud and clear** that all methods are async if not told otherwise.

Example : node.js uses this notation : [`fschmodSync`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.3/api/fs.html#fs.fchmodSync) and [`fschmod`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.3/api/fs.html#fs.fchmod)

But the most important is **to stick with the one you chose**.

Answer (score 4):

How about naming them the same and having a different signature to differentiate them (one with a callback function, one without)?

Otherwise, Adobe uses the "Async" suffix for ActionScript, which seems good enough too: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html

Comment: Good one, but they differ only by return type (Task<TResult> vs. TResult) and it does not affect method signature in my language.

Comment: In that case, I'd just go with the ASync naming convention. The advantage is that when you use automatic completion, you immediately see that there are two methods available.

Answer (score 1):

In the .NET framework, async methods start with "Begin": BeginDoSomething / DoSomething.

Comment: I believe method starting with `Begin` should have `End` counterpart, while our async method should return Task<TResult> client code could wait on.